# Using Multiple Linked Services in a Data Flow, Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, etl

Is it possible to use different linked services for source and sink in Azure Data Factory? Basically 2 different linked service in a dataflow?

By using "copy data activity" I can extract the data from one database with different linked service and load it to another database with different linked service. Instead of using copy activity, can I use a data flow for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use different linked services for the source and the sink within a data flow.

With a data flow, each source and sink can be configured to use a different linked service. This is how you can, for example, read data from a database or a file stored in Azure Blob Storage (via one linked service) and then write the transformed data to a different database or data lake (via the other linked service). This looks much like how the "Copy Data" task works, but with the enhanced possibility to make data transformations.

> Linked services are crucial in ADF as they establish connections
> between ADF and various data sources, including cloud services and
> on-premises services. They act as a bridge, holding the connection
> strings necessary to establish communication between ADF and external
> systems for data ingestion, transformation, and loading.
>
> To illustrate this, imagine a production line in a factory. The linked
> services are like the suppliers who deliver the raw materials required
> for the manufacturing process. Similarly, in ADF, linked services are
> responsible for delivering the data from various sources to enable the
> data integration workflows.
>
> Though a Dataset in ADF can be associated with multiple linked
> services, it's common to have a one-to-one relationship between a
> Dataset and a Linked Service. linked services in Azure Data Factory
> facilitate seamless connectivity between ADF and diverse data sources,
> ensuring a smooth and efficient data integration process.

[image]

Source : https://hackernoon.com/azure-data-factory-datasets-and-linked-services